# Спарсить html при помощи xpath

Tags: php, парсер, xpath

В общем есть рабочий парсер. Мне нужно просто, как то прописать правильно пусть откуда парсить.
Нужно выдрать значение What Lies Beneath из

```
<div id="headerFilm" class="feature_film_background country_num1">
<h1 class="moviename-big" itemprop="name">Что скрывает ложь</h1>
<span itemprop="alternativeHeadline">What Lies Beneath</span>
</div>
```

Собственно парсится при помощи такой строки.

```
$node_list = $xpath->query('//*[@id="content_block"]/table[1]/tr/td/div/table/tr[2]/td[1]/table/tr[1]/td/table/tr/td[2]/table/tr[2]/td/table/tr/td[1]/span');
```

Comment: Прежде чем создавать вопрос, попробуй воспользоваться поиском. http://php.net/manual/ru/domxpath.query.php
В документации сказано, как правильно воспользоваться методом query и что в него передавать, чтобы указать ему на элемент для парсинга.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$xpath = new DOMXPath(DOMDocument :: loadHTMLFile('example.html'));

$query = "//div[contains(@class,'feature_film_background')]";

foreach ($xpath->query($query) as $node) {
   echo $res['span'] = $xpath->query("span", $node)->item(0)->textContent;
}
```

example.html:

```
<div id="headerFilm1" class="feature_film_background country_num1">
    <h1 class="moviename-big" itemprop="name">Что скрывает ложь</h1>
    <span itemprop="alternativeHeadline">What Lies Beneath</span>
</div>
<div id="headerFilm2" class="feature_film_background country_num1">
    <h1 class="moviename-big" itemprop="name">Что скрывает ложь</h1>
    <span itemprop="alternativeHeadline">What Lies Beneath</span>
</div>
<div id="headerFilm3" class="feature_film_background country_num1">
    <h1 class="moviename-big" itemprop="name">Что скрывает ложь</h1>
    <span itemprop="alternativeHeadline">What Lies Beneath</span>
</div>
```